# Mysterious unidentified error message

Tags: macos, error

I keep getting this error on my Mac (see attached screenshot).  [image]

It happened yesterday and now today again.

The dialog is not associated with any application (at least, when I select it, it does not change the menu bar). In exposé the app title that it is given when mouse over is "UserNotificationCenter".

I can't find any info about this error on-line and I wondered if anyone had any ideas or any way to investigate it further.

Running 10.11.3.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure, but it looks suspicious. Poorly written, use of exclamation mark, reference to "PC" - it all looks weird. It's pretty useless too - you get an "OK" button and nothing else? What sort of dialog is that?!

Maybe check your date/time settings, but if there's no problem, I'd be a bit concerned about malware. Did you install any software recently?